# MySQL 8 host_cache returning wrong HOST for IP address

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

We're trying to troubleshoot a number of issues with the `host_cache` on a MySQL 8 server

The issues are all tied to a recent update where we tightened our user "From Host" definitions from `@"%"` to `@"%.ourdomain"`

An example issue was this morning when I attempted to connect over our VPN and was given an  "Access denied from IP Address" error. Checking the `performance_schema.host_cache` on the server my IP Address was listed but the "HOST" column held a `NULL` - which explains why I was denied access.

Ran `TRUNCATE TABLE` to flush the hosts and the issue persisted with the same entry recreated in the `host_cache`. (Flushing the cache has resolved the issue in 90% of the cases)

Reconnecting to the VPN 1/2 hour later I could now reconnect to the database.

**However** thia exposed a second issue. Checking the `host_cache` for the new IP Address the list host is *not* the host name for my machine.

So 2 issues

1. IP Address resolving as Null in Host cache
2. IP Address resolving to incorrect Host Name in host_cache

We'd like to keep the restrictions on the users, but would rather not use IP Addresses as suggested in the [MySQL 8 troubleshooting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-connecting.html) as we'd need to recreate users for each subnet that we have on our network

MySQL 8.0.35/Windows Server 2019

Comment: You really should move this question to the DBA sister-site of SO as it has nothing to do with programming or software development!